# Paperback novel about a sea or lake monster (I think)

Tags: story-identification, novel

For the past couple of days I've had random urges to read old books I can't remember the names of.

One in particular I read maybe 10 or so years ago. It was a kid/teen book and I'm really fuzzy on the details. I only remember that at one point, the protagonists (1 male, 1 female, both teenage) are in an underwater room or cave with a mural on one of the walls. The male protagonist is partially trapped in a tank with a pufferfish at the other end, and I think he kicks his way out? There's also something about a lot of pressure (like the bends) and the mural shattering when a door is opened in the room, relieving the pressure.

Sorry I can't recall more detail on this, it was pretty much half my life ago :)

Comment: did the novel have a scifi/fantasy element to it? the description you've posted doesn't sound like it.

Comment: I have a vague memory of a book that may or may not fit... did it involve an alien invasion where the main characters were a spoiled rich girl and the son of a genetic engineer?

Answer (score -1):

I doubt it but you might look at Deep Wizardry by Diane Duane.

Comment: Why do you think that this is the book?

Comment: It does match a few things in the description (Male and female teenagers and a decent amount of it happens underwater) That said I don't recall the scene described however it has been a while since I read it so I put it as a possible answer. I kinda doubt it is it but there is a chance.

Comment: You should take any information you have (and any external sources, plot summaries, reviews, etc.) and edit it all into your answer